# HttpClient behaving differently on ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, httpclient

My issue lies within the `PostAsync` action of the `HttpClient`.
A code excerpt used in my C# console app behaves totally different than the same code used in ASP.NET Core.

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "various", "params" } };
    var encodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);

    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, encodedContent).ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ().ConfigureAwait (false);
        return responseContent;
    }
}
```

Calling the method (GetData contains the upper code):

```
var unprocessedString = GetData("http://www.whatever.com/info.html").Result;
```

In the `unprocessedString`  I end up with a valid html string

The exact same code applied in my ASP .NET Core returns a completely different result.

The returned information looks like a huge JS script, I did check the fiddler request headers and the only difference is the `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` header being created by the ASP call, I did remove it and the results stays the same.

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<script>
a huge javascript function
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the page content.</noscript>
```

Comment: Er, no, `HttpClient` doesn't change the way it handles responses on different platforms. If there's a difference in the server response, then there's a difference in the client request.

Comment: The client requests were identical, that's why I've mentioned using the exactly same code (including the called server)  in the post. I think I got the problem, there are different versions of System.Net.Http between .NET and .NET Core

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did manage to find the issue. 
My http - post initially gets to the upper mentioned JavaScript that `redirects` my call to the seeked content ( This is what was happening when running the code from a .NET console app).
As far as I can see the ASP .NET Core implementation of the `HttpClient` differs in behavior because the exactly same code (and inquired resource) behaved totally different because the `redirect` never happened, thus the upper JS code ending up when I was reading info from that post.

This is how I've managed to fix it.

Firstly I declared an `HttpClientHandler` with the `AllowAutoRedirect` property to `true`.

```
 HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler { AllowAutoRedirect = true };
```

Then I just added this object to `HttpClient`'s constructor

```
 HttpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
```

Edit 1

I did manage to see a difference in the `System.Net.Http`  versions.
In the console app I have `4.0.0.0`
In the .NET Core I have `4.1.1.1`

Probably the latter version doesn't have the default behavior `4.0.0.0` had.